# Best way to render line that is being updated frequently by the device

Tags: ios, core-graphics, uibezierpath, cashapelayer, cgpath

So right now I have a persistent stream of data coming into the device and I want to draw a trend line live as the data is coming in.

Here's how I'm feeding test data into the system

```
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.100f
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(didGetTimerEvent:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];

    //
    // This is what's in the timer function
    //
    static CGFloat trigger = 0;
    const CGFloat weight = 50;

    // the line view, unsurprisingly, is what draws the line
    lineView.value = 12 * cosf(trigger) * M_PI * 0.6 + weight;
    trigger++;
    if (trigger > 100) trigger = 0;
```

Simple right, It's just a wavy line.

In the line view's setValue property, it appends the value to an NSArray. It then calls a render function where it creates a point and adds it to a CGPath, which is then in turn, set to the CAShapeLayer's path property. After that, CAShapeLayer handles the details of drawing said points to the screen.

Is this the best way to draw a line that updates this frequently?

If I only put a single chart on the screen the CoreAnimation instrument in the profiler reads that I'm drawing at 25 fps, so now I'm starting to rethink my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly standard optimization problem. First, you need to make sure you're drawing your lines efficiently. There are a ton of things around that:

- Turning off any fancy options that you don't really want in your `CGContext` (if you're using a `CGPath`, else on your `UIBezierPath`, in particular making sure that things like `setFlatness`, `setLineCap`, `setLineJoin`, etc. are set as simply as possible. You might even want to turn off `setShouldAntialias`.
- Make sure you aren't adding line segments that are shorter than a point. This is a common mistake.
- Don't let paths grow without bound. I've had decent luck with paths up to about 5000 elements on old hardware (iPad 3), but any hardware will be overwhelmed if you let the path grow forever.
- Eventually you may find it much easier to just draw the changes yourself in a CGBitmapContext. You can even just flip pixels directly if you want. It's hard to get nice anti-aliased lines that way, but you can definitely get super-fast.
- Do not update your curves faster than the screen refresh. This is another common mistake, where people calculate complicated curves 100 times a second when the screen only updates 60 times a second.

But mostly this is just a drawing optimization problem. All the interesting code is in the `setValue` method you're not showing. If you're already having trouble managing even 30fps, then yeah, you definitely be profiling your drawing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised it's showing 25fps. Your timer is only for 1/10s, so the line should be updating at only 10fps currently. Try making the timer fire faster, and look into using CADisplayLink instead - it's a better way to do updates at the frame rate of the device.

Comment: I am such an idiot. I just checked the call where I set up CADisplayLink and it returned me a nil! WTF. I'll check on it more when I get home.

Comment: So I fixed the bug to make sure CADisplayLink is calling it's update function and set my frameInterval to 1 but it's only at 27fps. The device is only going to be sending messages at the 10 per second anyway. Am I simply maxed out, since I can't get my render function to be called more often?

Comment: Instead of looking at the core animation tool's FPS, what do you see when you use the Time Profiler instead? That tool will show you hotspots in your codebase that are taking a long time. If you're only updating the data every 1/10s, then running the UI at 60fps doesn't necessarily matter. Are there other animations running? or is it just a static graph? Core Graphics might just be limiting the FPS b/c there's nothing to update, so it's deciding not to spend extra energy rendering new frames.

Comment: Sorry I dropped off there. Not a whole lot is going on. I'm going to open up a new question. I have a feeling there's some settings I'm missing, because I drop 5 of these things on the screen and the performance is pretty much the same. I have an iPhone 4s and a 6 and both have pretty similar performance. Let me put up my test project.